# How to fix an error with routing in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following in my routes.rb file:

```
match "/service/:product"           => "products#show_name"
match "/products/custom/"           => "products#custom"
match "/products/customform"        => "products#customform"
match "/categories"                 => "products#categories"
match "/search"                     => "products#search"
match "/about"                      => "products#about"

get 'category/:tag', to: 'products#category', as: :tag

resources :products do
    resources :reviews
end
```

I am trying to access the url "/service/birchbox".  When I do, I get an error saying

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"products"}
```

Any advice on how to fix this?  I am trying to get this url to go to the first route listed (to the controller products#show_name but is going to edit for some reason).

Here is some more information I'm seeing in the console.  It seems like it's going to show_name but I keep getting an error.

```
Processing by ProductsController#show_name as HTML
  Parameters: {"product"=>"birchbox"}
  Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."slug" = 'birchbox' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."product_id" = 14
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = 14 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = 'Product' AND (taggings.context = 'tags' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)
  Rendered products/show_name.html.erb within layouts/application (97.3ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 164ms

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"products"}):
  app/views/products/show_name.html.erb:42:in `_app_views_products_show_name_html_erb___2110533700820522490_70197663436420'
```

Comment: Did you restart the server after you made the changes?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes I did.  I also updated the question with more of the error I'm receiving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that in `views/products/show_name.html.erb` at line 42 you have something like this:

```
<%= edit_product_path %>
```

And this route doesn't exist. `edit` route requires product id. Try this:

```
<%= edit_product_path(@product) %>
```